# How connect MySQL and SQLite to Play Framework 2.2?

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc, sqlite, playframework-2.2

How connect MySQL and SQLite to Play Framework 2.2?

What format of Build.scala for JDBC driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the documentation here

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/ScalaDatabase